# Вывод переменной из Botmother в код Google Application Script

Tags: telegram-bot, google-spreadsheet, global-variables, sendmessage, user-variables

Создаю бота для вывода данных в виде строчного мини-отчета из Google Sheets по уникальному коду клиента.

Логика следующая:

Шаг_1: бот в отдельном id_chat пользователя при определенном запросе просит ввести уникальный код клиента;

Шаг_2: бот записывает ответ пользователя в переменную в числовом формате в виде {{my_object.inner_object}};

Шаг_3: Далее по логике эта переменная должна попасть в код GAS, через функции send_message и doPost вернуть массив данных, выбранный по указанному в переменной коду клиента из Google таблицы.

И на данном моменте появились сложности:

- как вывести переменную в код GAS из Botmother: в Botmother переменная обрамляется фигурными скобками '{{my_object.inner_object}}' и принимает числовой формат. Как и в каком формате обозначить такие данные в функции sendMessage?
- var url = telegramUrl + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + chat_id + "&text="+ text;      //правильно ли указывать в данном случае "&text="+ text, если введенные данные принимаются в числовом формате?
- далее принятая переменная должна попасть в функцию doPost -> найти в массиве по столбцу все строки, содержащие введенный уникальный код клиента -> вывести заголовки колонок таблицы по столбцам -> вывести все найденные данные построчно одним сообщением обратно в чат - такой функционал возможно реализовать? Если да, где найти информацию по теме? Ранее видела только выгрузку массива по текущей дате, а в данном случае необходима выборка из таблицы по ключу (уникальному коду клиента) из разных строк массива;
- function doPost(e) { //можно ли добавлять переменную из блока выше в данную функцию или она должна быть выведена новой переменной?

Добавила ниже код с которым работаю:

```
function sendMessage(chat_id, text) {          //переменная вводится в текстовое поле чата
var url = telegramUrl + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + chat_id + "&text="+ text;  
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function doPost(e) {     
var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
var chat_id = contents.message.from.id;
var text = "my_def"; // где можно найти информацию по формированию данных из гугл-таблицы построчно? Насколько понимаю, через конкатенацию оформить массив данных в таком виде нельзя.

sendMessage(chat_id,text)
```

Буду благодарна Вашей помощи и комментариям :)
Прорабатываю данный функционал впервые, любая информация будет полезна.

Спасибо!

Comment: Вторая "сложность", по-моему, скорее задание, чем проблема. Объясните, что вам непонятно, но не давайте задания.

Comment: Перенесите из комментариев кода в текст ваши вопросы. Так их удобней читать.

Comment: @Глеб, переформулировала вопросы. Спасибо за комментарий